# how to understand read preferences in mongo

Tags: mongodb, replication, database-replication, failover

I'm just getting started with mongoDB.  I am trying to understand how to set up my secondary database servers so that when there is no primary, the secondaries can be used to read data.  I believe the read preference I'm going for is preferredPrimary.

Now that I kinda understand which of the read preferences I want to test out, I'm trying to understand how to set up my replica set for preferredPrimary.
I've been reading through the following documentation:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-replica-set-tag-sets/

**Questions:**

1. Is this the right doc to follow to set up read preferences?
2. Assuming that it is, I want to verify that the tags names / values are anything that I come up with?  So specifically, the key used in the example "dc" is NOT a keyword in mongo.  Is that correct?
3. once I set up these tags, in my client, when I'm connecting to the mongo database, do i have to specify any settings?  I'm using a php front end, and I found this: 
   http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.setreadpreference.php
4. can you confirm that these tags replace the rs.slaveOK() method?

**Environment:**

- mongoDB version 2.6.5
- replica set with 3 members - one primary and 2 secondary servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. Yes, but the link that you provided is only for readPreference
   You also need to supply custom writeConcern (extract from link in a question):

   db.users.insert( { id: "xyz", status: "A" }, **{ writeConcern: { w: "MultipleDC" } }** )

Look into php driver documentation how to do that.

4. Yes, you may skip call to slaveOK in this case (especially, that in 95% cases you will be reading from primary)